# how to save only essential parameters in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

By default, the session saver saves all variables created and that results in very large checkpoint files. I want to save only model parameters and certain session variables, e.g. optimizer state and global step. What are the best practices besides white-listing variables during the saver initialization?

Comment: one method I am trying is to create a collection for other variable that I don't want to save, e.g. output variables. Then white-list all variables not in that collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some investigation (checkpointing with different batch sizes and printing out `all_variables`), i found that i was over-concerned. in fact, in tensorflow, results of Op are not saved, e.g. the `y` in `y = k * x + b`. thus, unlike `torch-nn`, you rarely need to worry about non-parameters getting saved.

Answer (score 2):

Saver by default gets variable list from `all_variables()` which is all variables from `GraphKeys.VARIABLES` collection. You can exclude variable from that collection by by using `Variable(..., collections=[]`). Or you could put it as another collection as is done in codebase for non-checkpointed `limit_epochs` variable

```
 with ops.name_scope(name, "limit_epochs", [tensor]) as name:
    zero64 = constant_op.constant(0, dtype=dtypes.int64)
    epochs = variables.Variable(
        zero64, name="epochs", trainable=False,
        collections=[ops.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])
```

Comment: If `collections=[]` the variable will never initialize. `collections=[ops.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES]` is the correct solution. It then needs to be initialized with `tf.local_variables_initializer()` to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a dictionary that contains all the variables you want to save, with the keys being their names as strings. Pass this dictionary into the saver.save() function. 
This is what the [api](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/variables/index.html#choosing-which-variables-to-save-and-restore) suggests.